# URL Rewrite - A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have a number of URL rewrite rules in place (they are all listed below).  When I browse "http://domain.com" I am forwarded to "http://www.domain.com/R:" with the message of "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)."  I want to be able to browse the site without "www" and be forwarded correctly.  I am not sure how to update or add to my existing rewrite rules.  This is .Net site.  I am hoping someone in the community can give me any hints.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Change to Lower" enabled="true">
        <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/R:{0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect StockNo" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^vehicles/detail/default\.aspx$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^stockno=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite StockNo" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^([0-9a-z\ ]+)$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="vehicles/detail/default.aspx?stockno={R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect StockNo And Desc" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^vehicles/detail/default\.aspx$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^stockno=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;desc=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite StockNo And Desc" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9]{4}[^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="vehicles/detail/default.aspx?stockno={R:1}&amp;desc={R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect StockNo Desc And Vin" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^vehicles/detail/default\.aspx$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^stockno=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;desc=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;vin=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite StockNo Desc And Vin" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9]{4}[^/]+)/([0-9a-z]+)/?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="vehicles/detail/default.aspx?stockno={R:1}&amp;desc={R:2}&amp;vin={R:3}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect Make And Model" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^vehicles/default\.aspx$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^make=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;model=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite Make And Model" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^([a-z\ ]+)/([a-z\ ]+)/?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="vehicles/default.aspx?make={R:1}&amp;model={R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect Make Model And SubModel" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^vehicles/default\.aspx$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^make=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;model=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;submodel=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite Make Model And SubModel" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^([a-z\ ]+)/([a-z\ ]+)/([a-z\ ]+)/?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="vehicles/default.aspx?make={R:1}&amp;model={R:2}&amp;submodel={R:3}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect Make An Offer StockNo" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^Vehicles/Make-An-Offer\.aspx$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^stockno=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="Vehicles/Make-An-Offer/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite Make An Offer StockNo" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^Vehicles/Make-An-Offer/([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="Vehicles/Make-An-Offer.aspx?stockno={R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect Make An Offer StockNo And Desc" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^Vehicles/Make-An-Offer\.aspx$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^stockno=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;desc=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="Vehicles/Make-An-Offer/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite Make An Offer StockNo And Desc" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^Vehicles/Make-An-Offer/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="Vehicles/Make-An-Offer.aspx?stockno={R:1}&amp;desc={R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to Default" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)default.aspx" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Add Trailing Slash" enabled="true">
        <match url="[^/]$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{URL}/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="test" />
</rewriteMaps>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your 2nd rule, it looks like the **R:** is not enclosed in brackets:

`http://www.domain.com/R:{0}` should be `http://www.domain.com/{R:0}`

Comment: This also dies for the same reason when redirecting to //{HTTP_HOST}:82/{R:0} but I MUST have ":82". Same issues as seen at the following post but they don't provide a solution, rather the cause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529307/rewrite-url-to-urlport-number